# How to delete a post depends on post author role?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post, wordpress-shortcode

I have created a custom post type and I have Woo Subscriptions. I would like to create a function that detects the post author role of each post.

If the author role is "Unsuscribed" then, change post status by that author to Draft. So with this, if users stops to pay the subscription, automatically their posts will not be shown.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use the [add_user_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_user_role/) action hook. This hook fires after a user has been given a new role.

```php
add_action( 'add_user_role', 'unpublish_non_subscriber_posts', 10, 2 );
function unpublish_non_subscriber_posts( $user_id, $role ) {
    if ( $role !== 'unsubscribed' ) {
        return;
    }

    $user_posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'author' => $user_id,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ) );

    if ( count( $user_posts ) === 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ( $user_posts as $post_id ) {
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I have tested it but it seems to be no change, the role change to unsubscribed automatically with Woo Subs, but the post status from the CPT of that Post Author, doesn't change to Draft.

Also I've tried the hook 'set_user_role' but the results were the same. Could you help me please?

Comment: @Sergixel you can try to use WooCommerce Subscriptions hooks like woocommerce_subscription_status_expired and/or woocommerce_subscription_status_cancelled. Read more here: https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/

Comment: Tested it! @Artemy Kaydash, but when a subscription is cancelled there is a critical error

Comment: I've been testing more, and the problem is that is not detecting the role of the Post Author!

    $user_posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'author' => $user_id,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ) );

    foreach ( $user_posts as $post_id ) {
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ) );
    }

That works fine and send all the posts from the CPT to draft

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, for some reason Wordpress deleted a 'letter' to the name of the role it was 'Pendiente' and wordpress print it as 'pediente', so that was the reason, thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome @Sergixel, I'm glad that you've figured this out :)